# Need to add a space after meta value in query_posts in wordpress for zipcode search

Tags: wordpress, zipcode

query_posts on wordpress has been trimming the last space of meta value added.
on my case I need to add a space after zip code on the meta query

```
 $meta_query[] = array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'address',
                                    'value' => $postcode,  // after postcode need to add a space
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                            );
```

But the last space is trimmed by wordpress . Is there any way to  add a space after the postcode value.
I have seen the same issue here
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246301/wp-query-meta-query-where-meta-value-ends-in-space

But it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this  and seems working
esc_sql($postcode.' %'),

```
$meta_query[] = array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'address',
                                'value' => esc_sql($postcode.' %'),
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            ),
                        );
```